# Calling a method of a parent interface with an (optional) parameter in the child interfaces

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface

Good day everyone.

I wanna be able to do something like this

```
public class CommandExecutor
{
    public List<ICommand> _commandList = new List<ICommand>()
    
    public void ExecuteCommands()
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < _commandList.Count; i++)
        {
             _commandList[i].Execute();
        }
    }
}
```

With this setup:

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
}

public interface IDirectionalCommand : ICommand
{
    
}

public interface IImpulseCommand : ICommand
{
    
}

public class ExampleCommand1 : IImpulseCommand
{
    public void Execute()
    {
        DoStuff();
    }
}

public class ExampleCommand2 : IDirectionalCommand
{
    public void Execute(Vector2 direction)
    {
        DoStuff(direction);
    }
}
```

But I don't understand how this could be done.
PS: sorry if the title doesn't fully capture the question here, I'm having a hard time wording this problem.

Answer (score 1):

That's wrong totally .. cause your interface have not defined any method named `Execute` which could accept a parameter ... what you are doing below code sample is nothing but hiding the interface method definition and defining a new  definition of `Execute()` which accepts a parameter ...

```
public class ExampleCommand2 : IDirectionalCommand
{
    public void Execute(Vector2 direction)
    {
        DoStuff(direction);
    }
}
```

What you can do .. define a overload of same method (*Method Overloading*) in your interface like below which accepts a `Vector2` type argument

```
public interface ICommand
{
    void Execute();
    void Execute(Vector2 direction);
}
```

Comment: The problem is, all deriving classes of ICommand would then have to implement 2 versions of the overload method. I would like to be able to call ICommand.Execute(), and have both IDirectionalCommands and IImpulseCommands call their execute method, even though the execute method of IDirectionalCommand requires a parameter.